# Need to sum the results of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

A query Q returns two columns - `DateOfWork` which is a `datetime` and `CallsTakenOnDate` which is an `int`.

That is, we get the number of calls taken by a particular phone exchange on a given date.

How do I create a function which will return the sum of the `CallsTakenOnDate` column for a particular phone exchange, over n number of days?

Table structure -

```
DateOfWork  | CallsTakenOnDate
-------------------------------
2013-10-5   | 200
2013-10-6   | 100
2013-10-7   | 700
```

etc.

I want to sum the `CallsTakenOnDate`.

Comment: group by only exchangeId

Comment: Can you include the structure of the relevant tables please?

Comment: @davidblaine The problem is while you gave a lot of details in your question, you did not show that you attempted to write this function or query.  This shows a total lack of effort to solve the problem by yourself.  Even if your attempt was awful, you should show something that you tried.

Comment: Reasons for downvotes? Possibly any of the following: You mentioned a "query Q" but didn't tell us what that query is. You didn't provide the table structure of the tables involved in query Q (you've mentioned phone exchanges - where and how do they fit in to all of this?). You didn't provide any evidence of what you've done to try to solve the problem for yourself. Basically it's a vague question with a huge deficit of important information and zero evidence of prior effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_getCountCallOnDate
(
      @DateFrom DATETIME
    , @DateTo DATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN (
        SELECT SUM(CallsTakenOnDate) 
        FROM dbo.PhoneCalls
        WHERE DateOfWork BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
    )

END
```

---

```
SELECT 
  DateOfWork = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.DateOfWork, 111)
, [Count] = SUM(t.CallsTakenOnDate) 
FROM dbo.PhoneCalls t
WHERE DateOfWork BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
ORDER BY t.DateOfWork
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had very much the same issue today:

```
select
  sum(CallsTakenOnDate) as count,
  DATE_FORMAT(DateOfWork, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") AS date
from
  raw_visits
group by hour(DateOfWork),day(DateOfWork),month(DateOfWork),year(DateOfWork);
```

This groups per day, but you can adapt it via the group statement.

Comment: That looks like MySQL syntax which will not work for SQL Server.

Comment: That is indeed mysql, did not see the MSSQL tag. Sorry for that. But the procedure via group should be the same...